# How to define a variable that's gonna be retrieved from localstorage (Chrome extension)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a variable defined like this (not sure if it should be with `let` or `var` in the first place):

```
let activated = false;
```

The first thing that the extension should do is check the value of `activated`. I think this is the correct syntax:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['activated'], function(result) {
    activated = result.activated
    alert ("activated: " + result.activated)
  });
```

After some logic, I want to change `activeted`to true, with this syntax:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({activated: true}, function() {
  console.log("activated changed to true: " + activated)
});
```

However, when I close and open the browser again, `activated`is set to false again.

How should I structure this in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: It probably means your code didn't actually write the value. Use a debugger to set breakpoints and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to acess a localstorage variable isn't by defining as I was doing in `let activated = false;`.

The way to add the variable retrieved from localstorage to the program's control flow should be done this way:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['activated'], function(result) {
    if (result.activated == value) { // Do something }
  });
```